# Chrome extension - Notification just work in apache

Tags: google-chrome-extension, notifications

I already configured my chrome extension to send notification like this:

[image]

I have a button that has a event that call createNotification. But the button just send notification if I'm running the extension on apache.

What I'm doing wrong?

Is equal that example http://jsbin.com/ziwod/1/edit?html,js,output
And for me this example just work when I click in "Run with JS".

This is my **manifest**

```
    {
  "name": "EXTENSION EXAMPLE",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description" : "This extension is...",
  "icons": { "16": "icons/16x16.png", "48": "icons/48x48.png", "128": "icons/128x128.png" },

  "omnibox": { "keyword" : "example" },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/19x19.png",
      "38": "icons/38x38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Launcher",
    "default_popup": "browseraction/popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions" : ["notifications"],
  "options_page" : "notification.html",
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
   "newtab": "newtab/newtab.html"
  },

  "devtools_page": "devtools/devtools.html"
}
```

This is my **notification.html** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYWQwB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your html file and the manifest file of `"manifest_version": 2` is that [Content Security Policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) is enabled by default. And Chrome developers chose to be strict about it and always disallow inline JavaScript code - only code placed in an external JavaScript file is allowed to execute (to prevent Cross-Site Scripting vulnerabilities in extensions). So `<button onclick="notifyMe()">` is not allowed in your html file. `onclick` attribute is an inline script. You should assign an ID attribute instead: `<button id="button">`.